# Авторству скульптора принадлежит мемориал?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Авторству скульптора принадлежит мемориал / или авторство скульптора принадлежит мемориалу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Авторство мемориала принадлежит скульптору.**

> [Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE&all=x)
>   АВТОРСТВО, -а; ср. Принадлежность произведения какому-л. автору. Установить а. текста. Признать а. за кем-л.
>
> Впрочем, по другой, недавней, гипотезе, ― **ее авторство принадлежит американской исследовательнице** Викки Хансен, ― глобальной вулканической катастрофы не было. [Александр Волков. Тайная жизнь Венеры // «Знание - сила», 2008]
>
> На колени его упал журнал, раскрытый на статье, **авторство которой принадлежало, судя по фамилиям, Мустыгиным,** но, конечно, написанной Андреем Николаевичем. [Анатолий Азольский. Лопушок // «Новый Мир», 1998]

Comment: ой. Ну да. Третий вариант - авторство мемориала принадлежит скульптору. Вопрос получился из жанра "я так устал всё это писать, что уже башка не варит". Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Оба хуже. 
Авторство - уже есть принадлежность. Авторству принадлежать ничего не может. "авторству принадлежит" - это жесткая тавтология.
Но вам это уже все сказали, не буду повторяться.

Строго говоря, даже варианты в цитатах М_Г не блещут изяществом изящно. Безупречно только "Мемориал авторства скульптора Такоя Сякоевича Разэтакова". Но с упомянутыми вариантами от М_Г я готов смириться. Но не с исходными.

Answer (score 1):

Мудрёные, нескладные, нежизнеспособные обе формулировки, несмотря на правильное сочетание вначале: *авторство скульптора*.

Говоря о произведении, его относят *к автору* или *авторству* мастера — причисляют к другим авторским творениям и применяют форму гораздо проще и человечнее рассматриваемых: *мемориал за авторством скульптора N*.

Comment: Хорошо, но, мне кажется, Александр искал аналогию для "перу писателя принадлежит книга"; тогда "мемориал за авторством скульптора" не так расставляет акценты.

Comment: Александру было угодно запутаться, и что искал понимает ли он сам?